# PayPal API with Laravel - Updating of data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, paypal

I'm trying to implement the `API` of `PayPal payment` with `Laravel 5.1`. But when I log in to `PayPal (sandbox)`, it uses the address I used in my account, and also it uses the name from PayPal account not the data from my website. That's my problem.

I want to use the data from my website because it doesn't make sense if I enter the shipping address (for example) from my website and not using it. Please see my code below for reference (Or comment down below for some details from me).

```
class PaypalPaymentController extends BaseController
{

    private $_api_context;

    public function __construct(){
        $paypal_conf = \Config::get('paypal');

        $this->_api_context = new ApiContext(new OAuthTokenCredential(
            $paypal_conf['client_id'],
            $paypal_conf['secret']
        ));

        $this->_api_context->setConfig($paypal_conf['settings']);
    }

    public function payWithPaypal(Request $request){
        $payer = new Payer;
        $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

        $price = 0;

        switch($request->get('amount')) {
            case '10 books':
                $price = 6200;
                break;
            case '20 books':
                $price = 12200;
                break;
            case '50 books':
                $price = 25200;
                break;
            default:
                return redirect()
                        ->route('bookstore.shipping')
                        ->with('danger', 'Please select the right amount of book/s.');
                break;
        }

        $item1 = new Item();
        $item1->setName($request->get('amount'))
                ->setCurrency('PHP')
                ->setQuantity(1)
                ->setPrice($price);

        $item_list = new ItemList();
        $item_list->setItems([$item1]);

        $amount = new Amount();
        $amount->setCurrency('PHP')
                ->setTotal($price);

        $transaction = new Transaction();
        $transaction->setAmount($amount)
                    ->setItemList($item_list)
                    ->setDescription('Books transaction');

        $redirect_urls = new RedirectUrls();
        $redirect_urls->setReturnUrl(route('bookstore.payment-status'))
                        ->setCancelUrl(route('bookstore.payment-status'));

        $payment = new Payment();
        $payment->setIntent('Sale')
                ->setPayer($payer)
                ->setRedirectUrls($redirect_urls)
                ->setTransactions([$transaction]);

         $patchReplace = new Patch();
         $patchReplace->setOp('add')
                    ->setPath('/transactions/0/item_list/shipping_address')
                    ->setValue(json_decode('{
                        "line1": "345 Lark Ave",
                        "city": "Montreal",
                        "state": "QC",
                        "postal_code": "H1A4K2",
                        "country_code": "CA"
                    }'));

         $patchRequest = (new PatchRequest())->setPatches([$patchReplace]);


        try{

            $payment->create($this->_api_context);
            $payment->update($patchRequest, $this->_api_context);

        } catch(\Palpal\Exception\PPConnectionException $e){

            if(\Config::get('app.debug')){
                return redirect()
                        ->route('bookstore.shipping')
                        ->with('danger', 'Connection Timeout.');
            }

            return redirect()
                    ->route('bookstore.shipping')
                    ->with('danger', 'Some error occured, sorry for the inconvenience.');
        }

        foreach($payment->getLinks() as $link){
            if($link->getRel() == 'approval_url'){
                $redirect_url = $link->getHref();
                break;
            }
        }

        Session::put('paypal_payment_id', $payment->getId());

        if(isset($redirect_url)){
            return Redirect::away($redirect_url);
        }

        return redirect()
                ->route('bookstore.shipping')
                ->with('danger', 'Unknown error occured.');
    }

    public function getPaymentStatus(){
        $payment_id = Session::get('paypal_payment_id');
        Session::forget('paypal_payment_id');

        if(empty(Input::get('PayerID')) || empty(Input::get('token'))){
            return redirect()
                    ->route('bookstore.shipping')
                    ->with('danger', 'Payment failed.');
        }

        $payment = Payment::get($payment_id, $this->_api_context);
        $execution = new PaymentExecution();
        $execution->setPayerId(Input::get('PayerID'));

        $result = $payment->execute($execution, $this->_api_context);

        if($result->getState() == 'approved'){
            // Send Email
            $email_data = [
                'number_of_books' => $payment->transactions[0]->item_list->items[0]->name,
                'shipping' => [
                    'street' => $payment->payer->payer_info->shipping_address->line1,
                    'city' => $payment->payer->payer_info->shipping_address->city,
                    'state' => $payment->payer->payer_info->shipping_address->state,
                    'country' => $payment->payer->payer_info->shipping_address->country_code,
                ]
            ];

            // Send email function here ...

            return redirect()
                    ->route('bookstore.shipping')
                    ->with('success', 'Transaction payment success!');
        }

        return redirect()
                ->route('bookstore.shipping')
                ->with('danger', 'Payment failed.');
    }

}
```

I also reviewed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39927124/paypal-php-set-no-shipping) but it seems like it cannot answer my problem. Also, `what if` the country has a province? How can we add that?

**Update 1**

1. Added new `Patch()` class.
2. Edited Code in `Try Catch`.

---

Note: The `accepted` answer will also receive the `bounty` plus the `up`.

**Update 2 with Tutorial**

1. For PHP/Laravel (I'm currently using v5.1), install this package
   [paypal/rest-api-sdk-php](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK)
2. [Create Sandbox account in PayPal](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/ph/webapps/mpp/merchant). Choose [Buy with Paypal](https://www.paypal.com/ph/signup/account?country.x=PH&locale.x=en_PH).
3. Continue until you see options, choose [Shop the world](https://www.paypal.com/ph/webapps/mpp/online-shopping).
4. Login to [developer.paypal.com](https://developer.paypal.com/).
5. Click [Accounts](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/). Click [Create Account](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/create).
6. Choose what country you want. Choose Personal (Buyer Account) in Account Type.
7. Add email address, avoid to use `-`. Use `_` instead.
8. Enter how much PayPal Balance you want.
9. Click Create Account.

**Make it live?**

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Going-Live

Comment: I assume you're not suppressing errors and have all the correct classes loaded? Maybe you could just double check those two points, 'cause your code seems to be -- almost -- a copy of the example code.

Answer (score 1):

After you have created the payment, try updating the address as shown in [this example](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/UpdatePayment.html).

```
$paymentId = $createdPayment->getId();

$patch = new \PayPal\Api\Patch();
$patch->setOp('add')
    ->setPath('/transactions/0/item_list/shipping_address')
    ->setValue([
        "recipient_name" => "Gruneberg, Anna",
        "line1" => "52 N Main St",
        "city" => "San Jose",
        "state" => "CA",
        "postal_code" => "95112",
        "country_code" => "US"
    ]);

$patchRequest = new \PayPal\Api\PatchRequest();
$patchRequest->setPatches([$patch]);
$result = $createdPayment->update($patchRequest, $apiContext);
```

> I also reviewed this link but it seems like it cannot answer my problem. Also, what if the country has a province? How can we add that?

Use the state codes [listed here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/state_codes/).

Comment: Updated with ID

Comment: Does the payment object you are using have an ID?

Comment: When I try to `dd` the `getId()` method, it returns null. Do you know why?

Comment: Can you post your full code? The ID of the payment should not be null if you are calling it after the `$payment->create($this->_api_context);` call.

Comment: You're right. It is now not null. I should just put it after the `$payment->create($this->_api_context);`. However, I'm still facing the same problem.

Comment: Okay, glad to hear you are not getting an error anymore. What is happening now, no exceptions but also not getting the desired behavior? Some other error?

Comment: I can now override the other fields like country and phone number. However, I cannot override the `province`, `first_name`, and `last_name`

Comment: `province` is not a valid field, use state. Likewise with `first_name` and `last_name`, use `recipient_name` like shown in the example.

Comment: I also tried to use `state` for the province but it is not overriding the Province/Region in paypal. `recipient_name` is working, however, if you have two or more words (e.g. `Erick Berkun`. So your last name will be `Berkun Drevnig`) in your first name, the second word in `recipient_name` will treat as `last_name`. Try to not login and pay with credit card (Or as guest).

Comment: That is the only last thing to solve this problem :-/  The province and the first name and last name.

Comment: That sounds correct, the second word is the last name? I'm not really sure if there is much you can do to change that behaviour if the API doesn't distinguish between first and last name. For the province/state, does it work for US addresses? Could you show an example of what data you are putting in?

Comment: Did you see the screenshot?

Comment: Laguna, PH does not appear on the list of supported state/province codes. See: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/state_codes/

Comment: Can you try 1) attempting this with a different address, perhaps a US address or another address from a country which is listed on that page 2) Try omitting the state/province field all together and see if that works, some countries it is not necessary for shipping purposes, I don't know the exact situation for the Philippines though.

Comment: So, it isn't available for Philippines?

Comment: I'm gonna give you the bounty for now, since it will end in 1 hour. But I still need your cooperation with this problem.

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure, I think it should support Philippines. Have you tried without giving it a state at all?

Comment: What is that? It sets the other fields but still asks the user for province/state? What are the options you get for that? Maybe you can inspect the select box to see which are the possible values.

Comment: It's a blank field in paypal. Check this link for the values: https://ibb.co/eLy8mo

Comment: Can I add you on other account? Like social media or gmail so we can talk faster? We also cannot talk longer here. We will just update your answer after we solve this problem, so other devs can also reference this thread.

Comment: I GOT THE PROVINCE NOW!! YES!! Now, the only problem is the First name and Last name

Comment: Hey Erik. Do you know how can I make it live after the sandbox?

Comment: Usually there is a separate API key for production/development purposes somewhere in your dashboard

Answer (score 0):

I have not used the PayPal API in a long while, but just skimming over the docs shows that the `payer_info` shipping address field is deprecated (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v1/#definition-payer_info) and suggests to use the shipping address in the `purchase_unit` instead.

According to the Docs, this should be set in the `CartBase` class with the `setItemList()` function (http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/docs/class-PayPal.Api.CartBase.html).

**Edit**:

So, for the package you are using, you'll need to add the `PayPal\Api\ShippingAddress` object to your `$item_list` variable:

```
$shipping = new PayPal\Api\ShippingAddress();
$shipping->setLine1('123 1st St.')
    ->setCity('Some City')
    ->setState('CA')
    ->setPostalCode("95123")
    ->setCountryCode("US")
    ->setPhone("555-555-5555")
    ->setRecipientName("John Doe");

$item_list = new ItemList();
$item_list->setItems([$item1])
    ->setShippingAddress($shipping);
```

`ItemList` class ref: http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/docs/source-class-PayPal.Api.ItemList.html#74-85

Comment: I'm not using that package. The only package I'm using is https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK

Answer (score -1):

I think [this is the relevant documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics/#overriding-addresses-stored-with-paypal) you are looking for.

> For people who already have PayPal accounts and whom you already prompted for a shipping address before they choose to pay with PayPal, you can use the entered address instead of the address the person has stored with PayPal.

Instead of using the address saved in their account,

> The payer is shown the passed-in address but cannot edit it. No address is shown if the address is invalid, such as missing required fields like country, or if the address is not included at all.

---

**Edit: Try something like this in place of what you have.**

```
$address = new ShippingAddress();
$address->setCity('Toronto');
$address->setState('ON');
$address->setCountryCode('CA');
$address->setLine1('123 Fake Street');
$address->setPostalCode('M1M1M1');

$payerInfo = new PayerInfo();
$payerInfo->setShippingAddress($address);

$payer = new Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');
```

Comment: This would be great. But can you include an example?  Coz I edited the `name` attributes in the `form`. This is the API I used: http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/CreatePaymentUsingPayPal.html

Comment: Also, what if the country has a province? How can we add that?

Comment: I tried it just now, but still not updating after logging in my `sandbox` account. Please see this screenshot: https://ibb.co/fHCgCJ

Comment: Isn't that what you want, the address prefilled?

Comment: That is the address in my sandbox account, not the address I used from my website. I want it to be the address I entered from my website.

Comment: May I ask if this is your real answer? or the one on the top? Could you please delete the other one?

Answer (score -1):

I haven't worked with PayPal very much, but I'm taking this from the official documentation, so I'm confident it will work for you. **[Overriding addresses stored with PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics/#overriding-addresses-stored-with-paypal)**. For a list of available variables you can use in the checkout page, see **[Auto-fill PayPal checkout page variables](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#auto-fill-paypal-checkout-page-variables)**.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <!-- Enable override of buyers's address stored with PayPal . -->
    <input type="hidden" name="address_override" value="1">
    <!-- Set variables that override the address stored with PayPal. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="John">
    <input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="Doe">
    <input type="hidden" name="address1" value="345 Lark Ave">
    <input type="hidden" name="city" value="Montreal">

    <input type="hidden" name="state" value="QC">

    <input type="hidden" name="zip" value="H1A4K2">
    <input type="hidden" name="country" value="CA">
    <input type="image" name="submit"
       src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif"
       alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
</form>
```

Or, from inside your script...

```
$address = new ShippingAddress();
$address->setCity('Montreal');
$address->setState('QC');
$address->setCountryCode('CA');
$address->setLine1('345 Lark Ave');
$address->setPostalCode('H1A4K2');

$payerInfo = new PayerInfo();
$payerInfo->setShippingAddress($address);
```

Here's the list of available province codes. You would use these two-letter strings for the "state" variable, just like you would a U.S. state. **[PayPal State and Province codes](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/state_codes/#canada)**

> Province name    |   Province code
>
> Alberta          |   `AB`
>
> British Columbia |   `BC`
>
> Manitoba         |   `MB`
>
> New Brunswick    |   `NB`
>
> Newfoundland and Labrador |  `NL`
>
> Northwest Territories |  `NT`
>
> Nova Scotia  |   `NS`
>
> Nunavut  |   `NU`
>
> Ontario |  `ON`
>
> Prince Edward Island | `PE`
>
> Quebec  |  `QC`
>
> Saskatchewan | `SK`
>
> Yukon |  `YT`

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Is the type of inputs necessarily to be `hidden`?

Comment: I tried it just now, but still not updating after logging in my `sandbox` account. Please see this screenshot: https://ibb.co/fHCgCJ

Comment: That's how those `<inputs>` appeared on the PayPal documentation. It has to be `hidden`, so no actual input fields appear where they are on the page. The `type="hidden"` is used to send static $_POST data. Have you tried clearing your cookies and your cache? Your app might be loading an old cookie

Comment: I'll try this. But how about this piece of code? https://ibb.co/bD856d . Should I still need this?

Comment: It seems like you could use either the HTML inputs, or the PHP script in your screenshot. If one of them doesn't work for you, you could always try the other. I'm unsure which would prevail if you used both.